# The order of Orthogonal group $O^{-}(2,q)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

I want to show that $|O^{-}(2,q)|= 2(q+1)$, When $q$ is odd prime power order.

I consider $V$ be a vector space on $F=GF(q)$ and $(V,f)$ be a orthogonal space.

I want to use matrix of form $f$ but I don't know what to say about the non squre element of $F$.

Comment: So what is your definition of $O^{-}(2,q)$. ${\rm GO}^{-}$, $ {\rm SO}^-$, $\Omega^{-}$, ${\rm PGO}^-$, ${\rm PSO}^-$, or ${\rm P}\Omega^-$?

Comment: @DereHolt $O^{-}(n,q)$ is the orthogonal group when $ V = W_{1} _| ...W_{r}_| U $ such that $W_{1}$ , ... , $W_{r}$ are hyperbolic spaces and U is a subcpace of $V$ with order 2 and base ${x,y}$ such that $f(x,x)=1$ , $f(x,y)=0$ , $f(y,y) = -a $ that a is a non squre element of $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}w&x\\y&z\end{array}\right)$ lies in $O^-(2,q)$ if and only if

$$w^2-ax^2=1,\ \ \ wy-axz=0,\ \ \ y^2-az^2=-a.$$

That $a$ is a non square element of $F$.

For the first equation, there are two solutions with $(1,0)$, $(-1,0)$ with $x=0$ and, for each $w \in F$,  there are two solutions $(w,x)$ with $x \ne 0$ if and only if  $w^2-1$ is a non-square.

It is a standard result in Number Theory that there are exactly $(q+1)/2$ values of $w \in F$ with $w^2-1$ a square, and hence $(q-1)/2$ with $w$ a non-square.

So there are a total of $q+1$ solutions $(w,x)$ to the first equation.

You can check that, for each such $(w,x)$, $(y,z)$ satisfy the second and third equations if and only if $(y,z) = (ax,w)$ or $(-ax,-w)$, so we have a total of $2(q+1)$ such matrices.

Comment: @DerekHoltThank you so much.